# select from influxdb records where in range of values

Tags: arrays, select, range, where-clause, influxdb

I want to get records from my influx db which are included in array of values.

SQL Example:

> select * from users where id IN (54, 55, 100, 300);

Is it possible to do the same in influxdb?

Comment: InfluxDB does not support `WHERE IN`, but using either RegEx or `OR` operators you may be able to achieve the same. See [this related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50993548/1039247) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

As of now this feature is not available in influx.

Reference :[Influx Docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/query_language/data_exploration/#description-of-syntax-1)

Answer (score 1):

not sure, if you could solve it. still not a feature in InfluxDB but you can use the following expression...

```
select * from users where "id" =~ /54|55|100|300/
```