# InfluxDB - Including multiple values in where clause based on tags

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to query data based on tag values. Is it possible to include multiple queries in the where clause . I could not find an operator similar to the IN operator in SQL.

`select * from students where rollNumber='1' limit 10`

students is the measurement and rollNumber is a tag. I want include multiple values of rollNumber in the query.

Any suggestions to solve the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

InfluxDB does not have IN operator, however it supports Go-lang regular expressions in WHERE clause for fields and tags. Regular expressions are enclosed with `/` and require adding `~` after comparison operator:

```
select * from students where rollNumber =~ /1|2|3/ limit 10
```

This will return 10 students, where `rollNumber` tag **contains** 1 or 2 or 3.

For a precise match the following should work:

```
select * from students where rollNumber =~ /^[1|2|3]$/ limit 10
```

**Note:** In case of filtering fields, if the type of fields is not string, regex will not work...

But as noted in the comments, using `OR` operator with explicit comparison should work better, as tag index can be used for more efficient querying.

Comment: Will this have any performance implications compared to single value in where clause since it uses regular expressions?

Comment: @Nirmal  slow when regexp very long...  better do it with `OR`  such as `rollNumber=1 OR rollNumber=2 OR rollNumber=3`

Comment: @WindyFields I was trying to understand the logic why it is slow for ages when the data is high your explanation however makes sense for me
Thanks.!