# Grafana + Influxdb templated variable selected with All is not passed as All in a link, instead passed as a comma separated string of values

Tags: grafana, influxdb

In dashboard A
I have a templated variable called region with datasource Influxdb.
It has values like “EAST”, “WEST”.
I defined it should also have an All option (checked Include All option).

The variable is passed inside a link to another dashboard B:
var-region_name=${region_name}

The same region variable is defined in Dashboard B.

When the user selects in Dashboard A the region as All option and in turn clicks to open dashboard B,
the region shows as {EAST,WEST} in dashboard B instead the desired value All.
This subsequently causes the query to have an empty result.

To fix, the user has to select the All option in dashboard B which is obviously not user-friendly.

How can I see that All passes as All from dashboard to dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can format your variable values using the syntax provide in the [grafana documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/reference/templating/#regex).

I don't have any experience with influxDB, but as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50983872/influxdb-including-multiple-values-in-where-clause-based-on-tags) answer, it uses regex for specifying multiple values in a query expression, so you should try '${yourVariable:regex}' in your query.